# How to duplicate a file in Notepad++ by Python with the same lexer

Tags: python, notepad++

I use a lot Notepad++ to write code. I often need to duplicate a file to use it as a template for another file I have to write. Of course, the new file should share the same lexer. How to do that?

Comment: What is the point of the question, if you already have a complete answer for that?)

Comment: The point is that I asked the question to several NPP fora and got no answer. Eventually I found a way to do it and I thought that it could be useful to share it with others. My understanding is that StackOverflow gives people the possibility to answer to their own question for this specific purpose. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin for Notepad++ that allows to write simple scripts in Python for that editor, called "Python Script".

I eventually wrote this code and it works, so I decided to publish it here just in case someone else has the same need. This is also to thank all people that helped me in the past answering my questions.

```
import os.path

# Get data from current file
anchor = editor.getAnchor()
lang = editor.getLexer()
filename = notepad.getCurrentFilename()
path, nameext = os.path.split(filename)
name, ext = os.path.splitext(nameext)

# Copy all text
editor.selectAll()
editor.copy()

# Clear selection
editor.setAnchor(anchor)
editor.setCurrentPos(anchor)

# Generate new file with same lexer and paste all text
newfilename = os.path.join(path, name + " (dup)" + ext)
notepad.new()
editor.paste()
editor.setLexer(lang)
notepad.saveAs(newfilename)
```